# A question in proof of a theorem in modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, free-modules

While studying algebra from Thomas Hungerford I have a question in proof of a theorem on page: 186 .

Its image:[image]

Question is in 3rd last line of the proof.

How does $x\neq x' $ implies $1_{R} \in I$?

I am not able to deduce the reasoning behind it.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "preceding argument" referred to here is the part of the proof where it was shown that if $\sum_{k=1}^m (r_k + I) \pi(x_k) = 0$ with $r_k \in R$ and $x_1, \dots, x_m$ distinct elements of $X$, then $r_k + I = 0$ for all $1 \leq k \leq m$.

Here, if $x \neq x'$, we have this exact situation, where $m = 2$, $x_1 = x$, $x_2 = x'$, $r_1 = 1_R$, and $r_2 = -1_R$. We conclude that $1_R + I = 0$, i.e. $1_R \in I$.

To put this another way, the preceding argument showed that the (potentially infinite) tuple $(\pi(x))_{x \in X}$ is linearly independent (which is stronger than showing that the set $\{\pi(x) : x \in X\}$ is linearly independent). In particular, the elements of the tuple $(\pi(x))_{x \in X}$ must be distinct, i.e. $\pi|_X$ is injective.